# How do you restrict access to a list in on a board in Trello?

Tags: trello

I am wanting to restrict access to specific iists on boards in Trello. I know I can restricted access to a whole board, but can I to a list?

Comment: What do you mean by access? Only able to view one list, and not others? Only able to move cards in a list?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to limit the visibility of a single list to certain members.